# Not clearing form data when user navigates to other page and comes back

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Not clearing form data when user navigates to other page and comes back without pressing submit button

Comment: Can you please elaborate or add any code snippet for the same?

Answer (score 0):

I've built something similar in the past using the `store` library - https://github.com/nbubna/store

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/9dy54x2g/9/

Index.html

```
<html>
<body>
  <form id="formExample">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    
    <button type="submit">
      Submit
    </button>
  </form>
  
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <script src="path/to/dist/store2.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript (script.js):

```
$(function() {
  $('#formExample').submit(function(evt) {
    // Remove the localStorage details for the form
    store.remove("formDetails");
  });
  
  // Watch for changes to the inputs
  $('input').on('change', function(evt) {
    var form = document.querySelector('form');
    store.set('formDetails', JSON.stringify($(form).serializeArray()));
  });

  // Bringing the data values back from storage (on page refresh etc)
  var values = store.get('formDetails');
  if(values) {
    var existingFields = JSON.parse(values);
    $.each(existingFields, function(key, val) {
        $("input[name='" + val.name + "']").val(val.value);
    });
  }
});
```